# How to implement multiple items in an android listview?

Tags: android, listview

I'd like to implement in a navigation drawer a list view where the first item is a linear layout composed of three subitems: a facebookProfilePicture, a textview and a logout button. And the rest of the items is just textviews.

I've seen different ways to do that, among them the viewholder patter but in the google tutorial on Udacity, they use a different way with their cursor adapter, the override bindview and some other method.

What should I use ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your question, I assume that you want to add custom items (of various types) to a list of items (either declared in code or coming from database).
Here you have to implement your own Custom Adapter (you can either extend the Adapter base class or you can extend Cursor Adapter if you are using a database), which will have different types of elements. For each type, you can declare a separate layout xml which you can customize as desired.

[This is a good link](http://www.tutecentral.com/android-custom-navigation-drawer/) which I myself used for something similar.

(If its dynamic i.e. if users can change or remove items, then you will have to implement your own ContentObserver which can be a little tricky, but there are enough resources online to help you with that!)

**Side Note:** Viewholder pattern is something different, and not related to different types of item in a list. It is used in lists for smooth scrolling by avoiding repeated use of `findViewById()`, so that the VM does not have to find the elements (like TextView etc) on the layout as many times as the no.of items. It finds them just once, and only populates as many times as the no.of items. Also

Comment: I did use this tutorial but I feel like it is not what's recommended by Google. Am I wrong ? Do you mind to share your code with me ?

Comment: Why he's not using getViewTypeCount()? Is it deprecated ?

Comment: Sorry, I cannot share my code with you :). I don't think there are many ways to implement this feature. I did use the `getViewTypeCount()` and it is not deprecated. I don't remember if this is there in the tutorial, but the tutorial is not 'official android documentation' so it might not be 100%, though it does have the working source, so you can download that and compare with your own.

Answer (score 0):

`CursorAdapter` is suppose to use when you want to retrieve data from the database or content provider.

If you query data from the internet just use normal adapter.

Answer (score -1):

CursorAdapter is a way of telling a ListView how to read data out of a cursor.  It's a convenient tool if you are reading simple data from a database and want to display it in your ListView.

The first question you have to ask is where is your data?  Will it be arriving in the form of a Cursor (e.g. are you getting it from a database).  If the answer is no, then cursor adapter is probably wrong.

Many other adapters take arrays (e.g. see ArrayAdapter), lists, or even maps in their constructors so there are other, simple, ways to supply your adapter with the data.

The "viewholder" pattern you mention is typically used when all the information for reading the layout  / data can't be supplied in the constructor.  It's used in conjunction with overriding the getView() method of the adapter.